# why I cant send and recv integers in a loop correctly

Tags: c++, sockets

I have the following code in my server program:

```
void sendAccounts(const Database& data, int socket, int32_t user)
{
   std::vector<int32_t> accounts = data.getUsersAccounts(user);
   uint16_t number = accounts.size();
   number = htons(number);
   send(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&number), sizeof(number), 0);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < accounts.size(); ++i)
   {    
        std::cout << accounts[i] << std::endl;
        int32_t account = htonl(accounts[i]);
        send(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&account), sizeof(account), 0);
   }
}
```

And the following code in my client program:

```
std::vector<int32_t> getAccounts(int socket)
{
    uint16_t n_accounts;
    std::vector<int32_t> accounts;
    recv(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n_accounts), sizeof(n_accounts), 0);
    n_accounts = ntohs(n_accounts);
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < n_accounts; ++i)
    {
        int32_t account = 0;
        recv(socket, reinterpret_cast<char*>(account), sizeof(account), 0);
        account = ntohl(account);
        accounts.push_back(account);
    }
    return accounts;
}
```

For some reason the client correctly receives the number of accounts but unable to receive account numbers, each recv returns -1, when I check errno it is equal to 0. What can be wrong?

Comment: `send()` does not guarantee to send all the bytes requested. You can ask it to send 4 and it may send 3. You have to check the return value and take appropriate action if not all the bytes were sent or if there is some type of error. Same goes for `recv()`. Note you don't tell us anything about the socket (for example could it be non blocking, in this situation recv returns immediately even if there is no data available to read on the socket).

Comment: Note that the issue Martin describes can be mitigated on `recv()` at least by using the `MSG_WAITALL` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `recv()` loop, you are casting the *value* of `account`, which is always 0, thus producing a null pointer. This is the main reason why `recv()` is failing.

You need to instead cast the *address* of `account` (just as you did with `n_accounts` above the loop). So, change this:

`reinterpret_cast<char*>(account)`

To this:

`reinterpret_cast<char*>(&account)`

That being said, on most platforms, `send()` and `recv()` take `void*` pointers, so you don't actually need to use `reinterpret_cast` at all on those platforms.

Since you mention `errno`, I assume you are *not* running this code on Windows. If you were, then `send()`/`recv()` *do* take `char*` pointers and thus would need the casts (and you should be using `WSAGetLastError()` instead of `errno`).